# Typescript custom type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface, pipe

If I have an interface in typescript like so

```
interface MyInterface {
  id: number;
  image: string;
  text: "one thing" | "another" | "anotherthing" | "anotherthing" 
}
```

How can I factor out my type for text with the pipes so I can use it multiple times as a type in my program? It seems like it should be simple but I'm not sure what the syntax is

For clarity I would like to be able to use it like

```
factoredOutType = "one thing" | "another" | "anotherthing" | "anotherthing" 

interface MyInterface1 {
  id: number;
  image: string;
  text: factoredOutType
}

interface MyInterface2 {
  name: factoredOutType
}
```

etc... I can't seem to find the syntax to this question so help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need the `type` keyword:

```
type factoredOutType = "one thing" | "another" | "anotherthing" | "anotherthing"
```

Not near a compiler now so can't really check but I think that works

Answer (score 0):

you can format string literal types using template literal if your types are related/dynamic. e.g.

```
type stringTypes =  `${'hello' | 'world'}_id`;
const a: stringTypes = 'hello_id';
```